# Изменить COLLATION таблиц планов SQL Server

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server, collation

Есть задача поменять в базе данных все `COLLATION` на `Latin1_General_CI_AI`. У таблицы созданные скриптами я исправил, но есть еще таблицы, которые к ним не относятся. В моем случае это таблицы `plan_persist_query_hints`, `plan_persist_query_template_parameterization`, `plan_persist_query_text`, `plan_persist_runtime_stats_interval`. У них стоит старый collation `Cyrillic_General_CI_AI`.

Вопрос: Нужно ли менял `COLLATION` у этих таблиц (имеет ли это смысл)? Если нужно, то как это сделать?

Comment: Смысл есть всегда.
Но если лень, то можешь COLLATION указывать при соединении таблиц

Answer (score 0):

Изменить параметры сортировки можно так:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.MainTable
ALTER COLUMN TargetColumn nvarchar(10) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI NULL
```

Но! Не зыбывайте что вы работаете с БД. Все референсные обьекты должны иметь одинаковые параметры сортировки.

Подробно: [How to Change the COLLATION](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3221/how-to-change-the-collation-of-a-sql-server-column/).

**Что касается таблиц планов:**
Необходимо менять параметры сортировки инстанса, подробнее о том как это реализовать, тут: [Changing SQL Server Collation](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3519/changing-sql-server-collation-after-installation/).

Comment: изменить таблицы планов таким образом нельзя

Comment: @mirypoko дополнил ответ, но я бы не торопился менять.